# CharField not saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I'm a relative django newbie, but I haven't been able to find that this is somewhere else. I setup django in accordance with the djangogirls tutorial and created a model that looks something like this:

```
class Grimmage(models.Model):
    gStart = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Not set'),
    gStartLat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    gStartLong = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    # [...]
    gUpdateDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    gUser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've done the database migration thing, and I try creating objects with Grimmage.objects.create(gUser=request.user). (I've tried other methods of creating objects with the same results.)

This is what I have in the respective view now (Why I'm not manually setting the default values again will be clear in a moment):

```
grim = Grimmage.objects.create(gUser=user)
grim.gStart = 'Not set'
grim.gFinish = 'Not set'
grim.save()
```

Ultimately, the views I'm making should check if the values have been changed from 'Not set' to move through getting values from the user. So, the object also has a method called 'whatsNext()' to return which value needs to be filled in next:

```
def whatsNext(self):
    ''' Returns a sting to indicate what value is needed next '''
    # Assumes the Grimmage has been checked for completeness and failed
    if self.gStart == 'Not set':
        return 'gStart'
    elif self.gFinish == 'Not set':
        return 'gFinish'
    else:
        return 'gTotalDistance'
```

Weirdly, it never returns the 'gStart' value because it's not equal to 'Not set.' If the view prints out the string of it, this is what I get:

((django.db.models.fields.CharField), )

If I manually set it again and print out the value, it works (temporarily). However, it quickly reverts to the ...CharField value.

For a while, I thought that none of the fields were saving, but the other (non-CharField) fields all display their default settings without me screwing with them. Further, I seem to be able to save values to them such that they persist.

Screwing around in the shell, I got this result:
[image: screengrab from interactive shell]

I'm at my wits' end. I've created other, simple django projects before and this was supposed to be the easy part. Naturally, I assume I've made a ridiculous mistake... but what?

Comment: Right now you have not defined a field, the comma defines a 1-tuple. The curse of the tailing comma, once again :(

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove comma after `CharField` in your model. With comma Python considers `gStart` attribute as tuple, not as model field.

```
gStart = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Not set') # without ,
```